# Getting an instance of BaseCorePipelineManager

Tags: pipelines, dependency-injection, federated-authentication

In the Sitecore doc [Configuring Federated Authentication](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/federated_authentication/configure_federated_authentication) there are instructions to generate the URL links to initiate Federated Auth -- the lines are:

```
using Sitecore.Pipelines.GetSignInUrlInfo;
/*
[...]
*/
var args = new GetSignInUrlInfoArgs(site: "website", returnUrl: "/");
GetSignInUrlInfoPipeline.Run(corePipelineManager, args);
```

How do I get an instance of the `corePipelineManager` in order to pass to the `GetSignInUrlInfoPipeline`?  I tried using the

```
var corePipelineManager = Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<BaseCorePipelineManager>();
```

But am getting an error below:

> CS1928: 'System.IServiceProvider' does not contain a definition for
>   'GetService' and the best extension method overload
>   'System.Web.Mvc.DependencyResolverExtensions.GetService(System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver)'
>   has some invalid arguments

Comment: Have you tried `var corePipelineManager = Sitecore.DependencyInjection.ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(BaseCorePipelineManager));`?

Comment: Marek -- you're correct - I was trying to put it directly into the razor but when I pulled it into the codebehind using your line it started working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct. Just add `Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection`namespace. It contains `ServiceProviderServiceExtensions` extension class that adds generic methods to the `IServiceProvider` interface.

At the same time, I would recommend you to use a constructor injection. It is supported in Sitecore and it lets you avoid a ServiceLocator anti-pattern.

Comment: Wait do you get extra points for answering my questions on your blog AND stack over flow :)

Comment: @Watson ;) That blog is not mine. I'm just trying to monitor issues for the features I've done :)